# MS Word monospace font is not monospace for spaces

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I want to create a report including c++ source codes with MS Word (macOS version).

Though I use monospaced fonts, white spaces are not monospaced.
White spaces have different width with letters.

How to write C++ source codes with space indentation.

[Spaces have different width with letters in some monospaced fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XJy3.png)

The right font MS Mincho is the right layout but I don't like the font.

Comment: Is this the same problem? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/monospaced-font-not-aligning-vertically-due-to/8d854439-41c1-4664-91c1-3f3e5de0f111

Comment: Exactly, but in latest MS Word,preference mentioned in that answere seems to be deleted.

Comment: Can you give a font name that doesn't work? (Most of the ones I tried here seemed to work OK so I haven't been able to reproduce the problem yet).

Comment: Menlo (Apple's font), Roboto Mono (Google's free font), Cascadia Mono (Microsoft's font). I inspected these fonts with FontForge and found these font have same width with letters and spaces but  white space width is more than 1/2 em which Microsoft insists white space should no more greater to. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/develop/character-design-standards/whitespace)

Comment: I had the same issue. I solved the problem by turning off the document option in a Windows Word.